# How to run WSO2 EMM Jaggery Web App in a WSO2 EMM Carbon Server?

Tags: wso2, jaggery-js

I have been using [WSO2 EMM](https://github.com/wso2/product-emm) product for a while. I imported [emm jaggery web app project](https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/tree/master/modules/apps/emm), which is located under  *modules/apps/* folder. into the WSO2 Eclipse Developer Studio and it is imported as a regular jaggery web app project.

I want to quickly change and run just the emm jaggery web app project (lets say some hbs files, page-layout etc.) and quickly review the impacts of the new design. Is there a way to do this quickly?

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found a simple solution to reflect the Jaggery Web App changes to the running system via symbolic links.

After you have build the system successfully, the zip archive file is created at the `product-emm/modules/distribution/target/wso2emm-1.1.0` directory.

Unzip the file and for linking Jaggery Web Apps locate to the `product-emm/modules/distribution/target/wso2emm-1.1.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps`directory where the web applications are bundled.

And give symbolic links by removing the old bundled ones and linking apps like `ln -s ../../../../../../../apps/emm/ .` to the `product-emm/modules//apps/` location where the real development is going on.

Final picture will look like something like this. After this you can change the code and see the effect without reloading the server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by changing the necessary files then reloading the emm project from web-browser as you normally do for other web applications written in HTML, js & css. This can be tested by changing the files in emm jaggery application in WSO2 EMM product & there is no need for using a separate server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but emm web app project, is not a detached project it uses or it has been used by some other projects such as store, publisher etc. which are located at the /modules/apps/* directory as well. In this case, it needs other apps up & running. How can it be tested in this environment?